# Will jquery live work for $('#somebutton').data('events').click?

Tags: javascript, jquery

The events for a button get wired up after the page loads, so I need to use live for this.

Will live work for this:

```
$('#somebutton').data('events').click;
```

Comment: What is `$('#somebutton').data('events')`?

Comment: @Rocket, I guess the [`.data()`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.data/) function.

Comment: @Darin: I meant, what is the value of that?

Comment: How in the world is this "question" getting upvotes?  It's unintelligible.

Comment: Also, ".live()" is used when *elements* are created and added to the DOM dynamically; altering event handling after page load time does not (of necessity) call for using ".live()".

Answer (score 3):

Only if `$('#somebutton').data('events').click` already has the click function in it when you call `.live`.  Otherwise, you're passing a null value.

This is to say, the behavior specified by `.live` kicks in when the button gets created, but it doesn't re-evaluate a data reference to its handler at that point; it uses whatever value was sent to it when it was first called.

You can send it a function that does the same thing, though:

```
$('#somebutton').live('click', function(e) {
    $(this).data('events').click(e);
});
```

Comment: The thing is, @chaos, it's just not really accurate to say that ".live()" does **anything** when the button is added to the DOM.

Comment: Nyergh.  Okay, yes, the `.live()` function itself is not actually running at that time.  I am at a loss for a more precise phrasing that would not just add confusion to the situation of an already clearly-very-confused individual such as OP; would you care to supply one?

Comment: Gave it a try with "the behavior specified by `.live`"; is that any better?  (Incidentally, I removed the "added to the DOM" language because it turns out that `.live` can affect objects that haven't been added to the DOM, which is what I thought you were talking about in the first place.)

Comment: I think that's lovely, @chaos :-)